# MassTransit with RabbitMQ: recovering the error queue

Tags: rabbitmq, masstransit

This is probably a very simple answer, but I'm not seeing an obvious solution in the MassTransit docs or forums.

When you have some messages that have been moved over to the error queue in RabbitMQ, what's the best mechanism for getting them back into the processing queue? Also, is there any built-in logging of why they got moved over there in the first place?

Comment: I just ran into this and wrote a quick post about using BusDriver to move messages from one queue to another. http://josephvano.wordpress.com/2012/09/11/masstransit-moving-messages-from-error-queue/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Enable logging with the right plugin (NLog, log4net, etc) and failures should be in the log, assuming the right log level is enabled.

There is no great way to move messages back. [Dru](http://drusellers.com/) has worked on a `busdriver` tool https://github.com/MassTransit/MassTransit/tree/master/src/Tools/BusDriver. This, I believe, will allow you move items from one queue to another - but it's not a tool I've used. I have historically written tools that are related to business processes to move items back to the proper queue for processing that ops will manage.

Comment: Hi Travis. I've enabled logging with a log level of 'Debug' using NLog and I'm able to log from my application. However, I'm not seeing any log entries from masstransit even though messages are still going to the error queue. Could you pls help with what I could be missing?

Comment: I'm not actually sure how NLog works. In log4net, I have set to MassTransit filter to Debug or the global one. Hit up the mailing list  and ask there, someone will have a better idea than I will. https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/masstransit-discuss

Comment: Oh, have you included the MassTransit NLog integration nuget package?

Comment: @Travis: Can you please give me example of command we need to run to copy message from one queue to another

Comment: https://groups.google.com/d/msg/masstransit-discuss/sHOCyNdKo1A/2ui8cPp28vwJ on the mailing list has an example of who they used it.

Comment: @Travis If you have written business related tools to move messages between queues, could you give a simple example on what that would look like.

Comment: I've worked with tooling we've built that goes through each item in the queue and allowed the person reviewing to make minor edits or to replay the transaction from an earlier state. It would show the message, the errors related to that transaction, and give them options on how to interact with it.

Comment: That's pretty nitfy. But, how is the simple BusDriver tool any different than what rabbitmq management tools and UI provide?